# docker.image().inside() doesn't run sh command inside my Image

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am writing a Jenkins pipeline. I am creating a docker image that runs a command from python virtualenv(inside the image). I am creating this virtual env while creating the docker image. When I do below:

```
stage() {
  steps {
    script {
      def dockerImage = docker.build('-f <path_to_dockerfile> .')
      dockerImage.inside() {
        sh 'venv/bin/isort src'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It says that 'venv/bin/isort' is not found. if I do a 'pwd' then it shows path to the host machine jenkins workspace. Jenkins workspace has a checkout copy from my git repo and repo doesn't contain the venv(Virtualenv). But, I expect this should return path inside my docker container.

My Docker file :

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine

RUN apk update && apk add bash && apk add build-base

RUN mkdir /app

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements /app/requirements

COPY Makefile /app/

RUN make venv/.venv_build
```

Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: have you tried  `sh '/app/venv/bin/isort src'` ?

Comment: If I do `pwd` , it shows  the path of jenkins workspace in host machine. And, this path doesn't have `venv` and  `/app/venv/bin/isort` is the path inside docker image. From this I assume, my command is not being run inside the image.

Also, I expect ```dockerImage.inside() {
        sh 'venv/bin/isort src'
      }``` should trigger `docker run -it -v venv/bin/isort src`. But I don't see this in my jenkins job log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look carefully at the Jenkins logs, the `docker run` command it executes does a lot of things to simulate the workspace environment.  `image.inside { ... }` bind-mounts the workspace directory into the container at the same path, overrides the current directory to be the workspace directory, and overrides the default command, among other things.

I think there are two good options here:

1. Explicitly specify the absolute path to the program when you `sh` the command.

   ```
   dockerImage.inside() {
     sh '/app/venv/bin/isort src'
   }
   ```
2. Use `image.run` to run the image "normally", maybe with a `-v` option to bind-mount parts of the workspace directory into the container.  This is the same way you'd `docker run` the container.

   ```
   dockerImage.run("-v ${env.WORKSPACE}/src:/app/src")
   ```

   This construct would run whatever the default `CMD` is in your image; that line seems to be missing from the Dockerfile in the question.

Comment: Option one should be preferred over two, since option two would be replaced by a `agent { dockerfile true }` to do all of that automatically correctly in one line.

Comment: Thanks @David and @Thanh! Your suggestion worked. I was misunderstanding something. Thanks for your help!